# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin - different queries used for the filter tab vs the index data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm new to ruby, rails, ActiveAdmin.

I have some custom filters that return the correct data and I can see the correct number of records appearing in the filter tab.

I notice that a different query is used to actually render the data in the index view and I don't know why.

With further investigation, I think my issue is related to PAGING in ActiveAdmin. I have a specific request where I have my own LIMIT of displayable adverts set to three, but this limit is being overridden by the paging operation within ActiveAdmin.

I tried setting paginate to false, but this has not had any effect.

```
# The Query should be
# [ my query is here, see image below ]) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3

# Effect with paginate = true to my query is:
# [ my query is here, see image below ]) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
config.paginate = true

# Effect with paginate = false to my query is:
# [ my query is here, see image below ]) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0
config.paginate = false


# Expected SQL - This is what gets used on the tabs at top of screen
SELECT "advertisements".* FROM "advertisements" WHERE "advertisements"."site_section" = 'Signed In' AND "advertisements"."region_id" IN (10) AND (active = 'true' AND start_date <= '2014-12-01 13:00:00.000000' AND end_date >= '2014-12-01 13:00:00.000000') ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3


# Actual SQL - This is what is used to render the index
SELECT "advertisements".* FROM "advertisements" WHERE "advertisements"."site_section" = 'Signed In' AND "advertisements"."region_id" IN (10) AND (active = 'true' AND start_date <= '2014-12-01 13:00:00.000000' AND end_date >= '2014-12-01 13:00:00.000000') ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Listed below is a screenshot with pretty thorough log and visual cues. I have also listed my Model and ActiveAdmin code.

[image: Log and Visual issues]

**ActiveAdmin Code**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Advertisement do
  menu :parent => 'Partner', :label => 'Adverts', :priority => 2

  scope :all, :default => true do |rows|
    logger.block '1'
    if params[:as] == "test_adverts"
        rows
    else
        rows
    end
  end

  scope :live do |rows|
    logger.block '2'
    logger.kv 'SQL', Advertisement.get_ads_by_location_aa(params, 0).to_sql
    logger.kv 'COUNT', Advertisement.get_ads_by_location_aa(params, 0).count
    Advertisement.get_ads_by_location_aa(params, 0)
  end
  scope :next_month do |rows|
    logger.block '3'
    Advertisement.get_ads_by_location_aa(params, 1)
  end

  filter :staffrooms
  filter :advertisement_category
  filter :region
  filter :active
  filter :name
  filter :start_date
  filter :end_date
  filter :is_workible
  filter :site_section, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { Advertisement::SITE_SECTION_TYPES }
  filter :by_loco, label: "Location XXX", as: :string, :class => "select-location" #, collection: %w[ New Active Inactive ]

  sidebar :by_location, :if => true do # proc{ params[:as] == "test_adverts" } do
    logger.block '4'
    render partial: "index"
  end

    # ---------------------------------------------
    # Internal Helper Classes
    # ---------------------------------------------

  class RenderAdvertisementIndex < ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexAsBlock
    def self.index_name
        PL.block '5'
      "test_adverts"
    end
  end


    # ---------------------------------------------
    # Index Pages
    # ---------------------------------------------

    index do #|html|
        logger.block '6-Index'
        selectable_column 
        default_actions_extended

        column_bool_yn :active
        column :region
        column :advertisement_category, :label => 'Category'
        column :site_section, :label => 'Section'
        column :name
        column :image_url
        column_bool_yn :is_workible
        column_date_ddmmyy :start_date
        column_date_ddmmyy :end_date
    end

  index as: RenderAdvertisementIndex do |r|
    logger.block '6-RAI'

    div :for => r do
      div do
        h3 "#{r.name} - #{r.region.name}"
        span link_to(image_tag(r.image_url)), :class => 'pull-right'
        hr
      end
    end
  end

    # ---------------------------------------------
    # Editor
    # ---------------------------------------------

    form do |f|
    f.inputs "Advertisement" do |advertisement|
            f.input :active
        f.input :region_id, as: :select, :collection => Region.all, :include_blank => false
        f.input :advertisement_category_id, as: :select, :collection => AdvertisementCategory.all, :include_blank => false, :label => 'Category'
        f.input :site_section, :as => :radio, :collection => Advertisement::SITE_SECTION_TYPES, :label => 'Section'
        #f.input :site_section, :as => :radio, :collection => Advertisement::SITE_SECTION_TYPES.map { |e| [e, e]  }, :label => 'Section'
        #f.input :site_section, :as => :radio, :collection => [["Male", false], ["Female", true]], :label => 'Section'
        f.input :name
        f.input :image_url
        f.input :target_url
        f.input :start_date
        f.input :end_date
        f.input :is_workible, :label => "Is Workible Advert"
    end

    f.inputs "Filter To Specific Pages" do |advertisement|
        f.input :staffrooms, :label => "Filter on Industry Pages", :collection => Staffroom.where(staffroom_type: 'Industry'), :as => :check_boxes
        f.input :staffrooms, :label => "Filter on Communities Pages", :collection => Staffroom.where(staffroom_type: 'Site'), :as => :check_boxes
    end

        f.buttons
    end

    # ---------------------------------------------
    # Viewer
    # ---------------------------------------------

    show do |r|
    attributes_table do
        row :active
        row :region
        row :advertisement_category
        row :site_section
        row :name
        row :image_url
        row :target_url
        row :start_date
        row :end_date
        row :is_workible
        row :category do
            r.advertisement_category_id
        end
    end
    end

    controller do

    def scoped_collection
      logger.block '7'
      logger.pretty_params(params)

      Advertisement.includes(:region, :advertisement_category)
    end

end
```

**Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: advertisements
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  active       :boolean
#  name         :string(255)
#  content      :string(255)
#  image_url    :string(255)
#  target_url   :string(255)
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#  region_id    :integer
#  site_section :string(255)
#  start_date   :date
#  end_date     :date
#  is_workible  :boolean
#
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init
  attr_accessible :active, :name, :content, :image_url, :target_url, :advertisement_category_id, :region_id, :site_section, :start_date, :end_date, :is_workible, :staffroom_ids

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Relationships
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  has_and_belongs_to_many :staffrooms
  belongs_to :advertisement_category
  belongs_to :region

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Constants
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  SITE_SECTION_TYPES = ['Public', 'Signed In']

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Validations
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  validates :name, presence: true
  validate :custom_validation

  def custom_validation
    self.image_url = applyHttp(self.image_url)
    self.target_url = applyHttp(self.target_url)
  end

  def applyHttp(url)
    unless url[/\Ahttp:\/\//] || url[/\Ahttps:\/\//]
        return "http://#{url}"
    end
    return url
  end
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Queries
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  def self.live(month_offset = 0)
    date = ::Time.zone.now.midnight+month_offset.month
    where(["active = ? AND start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", :true, date, date])#.includes(:region,:advertisement_category)
  end

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Sample - Cremorne Point
  #
  # Advertisement.get_ads_by_location('Signed In',4921,5).pluck_all('id, name, site_section') 
  #
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Sample - Hellendsburg
  #
  # Advertisement.get_ads_by_location('Signed In',7310,5).pluck_all('id, name, site_section') 
  #
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def self.get_ads_by_location(section, location, month_offset = 0, ad_count = 3)
    location = Location.find(location)

    region_ids = Region.near(location.location, 50).pluck(:id)

    live().where(site_section: section).where(region_id: region_ids).order("RANDOM()").limit(ad_count)
  end

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Active Admin - Accessors
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  def self.get_ads_by_location_aa(params, month_offset)
    location_id = params["q"]["location_id"] unless params['q'].blank?

      location_id = location_id.to_i
      Advertisement.get_ads_by_location('Signed In', location_id, month_offset)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html#index_pagination):

> You can set the number of records per page per resources:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  config.per_page = 10
end
```

Comment: The problem with that answer is that it is not configurable, the current number of adverts being returned (3 in the example) is a query parameter from custom panel. How do I stop page from interacting at all with my query. Even turning it off does not stop ActiveAdmin from altering my call to limit.